# Favicon for static HTML page

Tags: html, favicon

I'm trying to upload a simple favicon to my HTML page. I've been browsing the web for answers and I'm being told to "upload the image to my server." My files are uploaded to GoDaddy, and I'm not exactly sure how to do this. Basically, how do I get my website to have the `/favicon.ico` extension?

Comment: Please search for an answer first next time: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3835/adding-a-favicon-to-your-website-builder-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create a favicon.ico with your logo or image and upload it to the folder where your index.html (or your default page).

You can easily create favicon (favicon.ico) from this online tools
http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/

I've used this to generate favicon for my website. 
For eg: For my website ([mansoor.in](http://mansoor.in/)) I've uploaded [favicon.ico](http://mansoor.in/favicon.ico) here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's live at http://kenfedor.com. I heard it takes a few days for it to actually show up next to the URL though. Is that true?

Comment: @KenFedor No I can see your favicon now.